# Loops in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am experimenting to convert one of my CoffeeScript libraries to TypeScript. The experience is OK so far except I cannot find an equivalent for

```
locations = (new Location p.lat, p.lng for p in points)
```

Do I have to write the old fashion `for(i = 0; i < len; i++)` kind of loop for TypeScript?

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript adds to the declaration syntax of JavaScript. It leaves the expression syntax largely untouched so you would, as they say, use your favorite method. Personally, I would use `map()` so it would look like,

```
var location = points.map(p => new Location(p.lat, p.lng));
```

but this only works in ES5 or if you use a `map()` polyfill.